# Is there a way to use a let string as a key name? - swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, filter

I have a string created when I select a table cell, and a class called cars:

```
class car{
   name:string
   color:String
   type:string

}

let itemselecionado = ""
let lista = ["name","color","type"]
let listacars = [car1,car2,car3]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     itemselecionado = lista[indexPath.row] // 
}
```

can I transform this string into a class key name to filter a table?

Ex:

```
listacars = listacars.filter({ $0.itemselecionado.lowercased().contains("ok") })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do it with strings, unless you use a dictionary instead of a class.

However, you could use a `KeyPath` instead of a `String`:

```
struct Car {
    let name: String
    let color: String
    let type: String
}

let items: [KeyPath<Car, String>] = [\.name, \.color, \.type]
let cars = [
    Car(name: "Audi", color: "black", type: "A5"),
    Car(name: "Fiat", color: "red", type: "Uno")
]

let row = 1 // color

let selectedItem = items[row]
let filteredCars = cars.filter { $0[keyPath: selectedItem].lowercased().contains("r") }
print(filteredCars) // [Car(name: "Fiat", color: "red", type: "Uno")]
```